# .NET Core set up on Windows 10

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am building a web application (beginner in ASP.NET Core) and I wanted to check if the correct installation is done on my machine: Windows 10.
Required installation: .NET Core 3.0

After running "dotnet --info" on my command line I got this:

Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

It seems like I have .NET Core 3 5 and 6. I want to make sure that my installation is correct. Any help?

Comment: "Required installation: .NET Core 3.0" - that went out of support a *very* long time ago. (3.1 and 5.0 are also out of support now.) Why do you want that? It's unclear what problems you're running into, to be honest... do you have Visual Studio installed? What happens when you *try* to create an ASP.NET Core app?